# Is OAuth (2.0) is the right choice to make WCF WebService secure?

Tags: design, .net, architecture, rest, wcf

I have WCF webservice which serves to various mobile application. This was implemented with typical HTTPS/SSL. But there are some cases like Replay Attack needs to be considered in the security aspect.

OAuth 2.0 looks like a viable solution for this problem (using nonce). And I can see some examples on web using DotnetOpenOAuth library to implement a server.

Is OAuth is a right choice to use with WCF services?
Is there any alternatives with .NET framework/Microsoft technologies to implement a secure WCF server?